# Unable to install capybara-webkit with OS X Sierra

Tags: ruby, qt, macos-sierra, capybara-webkit

I've been trying to install the Capybara-Webkit gem with bundler and after following these instructions: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#macos-sierra-1012

I keep running into the error of the Makefile not being found. I've updated Homebrew, the gem system, and updated Xcode 8 with cli tools to no avail. Would really appreciate any help!

```
sudo gem install capybara-webkit PATH=/Users/caren/Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/bin:$PATH gem install capybara-webkit
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/caren/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161108-5610-m00680.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/caren/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-gl-dir
    --without-gl-dir
    --with-gl-include
    --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
    --with-gl-lib
    --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/caren/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/caren/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/gem_make.out
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'PATH=/Users/caren/Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/caren/.nvm/versions/node/v5.4.0/bin:/Users/caren/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/caren/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'gem' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'install' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: installr, instant, instana, instacli, instapi
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/caren/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161108-5610-97n2eh.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/caren/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-gl-dir
    --without-gl-dir
    --with-gl-include
    --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
    --with-gl-lib
    --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/caren/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/caren/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: how did you install QT?

Comment: you should be running `PATH=/Users/caren/Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/bin:$PATH gem install capybara-webkit`  not `gem install capybara-webkit PATH=/Users/caren/Qt5.5.1/5.5/clang_64/bin:$PATH gem install capybara-webkit` and when/if that fails look at the mkmf.log mentioned in the error message to see what errors are occurring

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/256232/how-can-i-get-qmake-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @fabersky I installed it from the Qt website.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following did the trick for me (using Homebrew):

```
brew install qt5 --with-qtwebkit
brew link --force qt5
gem install capybara-webkit
```

Note: It will take a while to install the first step, and you'll need to have Xcode installed.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Tried your steps and worked out for me. :)

Comment: Thanks mate! Took a long time to compile/make but did worked out. Many many Kudos! :)

Comment: no kidding about that first command taking a very long time.  all 3 command worked like a charmed! thanks mate!!

Comment: Just a side note that this will break on brew upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help someone.

```
brew install qt5 --with-qtwebkit
brew install qt@5.5 or brew reinstall qt@5.5

echo ‘export PATH=“/usr/local/opt/qt@5.5/bin:$PATH”’ >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

brew unlink qt@5.5 && brew link --force qt@5.5
```